# Is there a way I can specifically choose from a list to grab a number

Tags: python

I have started making a little game in python, but I got stuck at one point with a problem. This is the code I am running right now.

What I wanted to do is, after shuffling the roles, assign a number to them (which I was using this for), and then I want to be able to choose a number (in this case 0-3, because there are 4 roles: Invest, One, Two, Three) and it would tell me which number I chose and who is assigned to that number (for example I would choose 2, and it would tell me that "Three" is assigned to 2).

```
Roles = ["Investigator","One","Two","Three"]
random.shuffle(Roles)
n = random.randint(0,len(Roles)-1)
print(n+1)
print(Roles[n])
----------------------
```

Comment: do you mean get the index of the an item in the list?

Comment: `print(list(enumerate(Roles)))`

Comment: I'm a little confused. Your code seems to already solve the problem.

Comment: You can also use `randrange` so you don't have to `-1` the upper limit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dictionary:

```
import random
Roles = ["Investigator","One","Two","Three"]
random.shuffle(Roles)
final_data = {}
for i in range(len(Roles)):
   while True:
      val = random.randint(0,len(Roles)-1)
      if val not in final_data:
          final_data[val] = Roles[i]
          break
```

However, a solution alternative to your original idea:

```
final_data = {i:a for i, a in enumerate(Roles)}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also `enumerate` the roles after shuffling, and then use [`random.choice`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/random.html#random.choice) to select one of the `(index, value)` pairs from that enumeration.

```
>>> roles = ["Investigator","One","Two","Three"]
>>> random.shuffle(roles)
>>> roles = list(enumerate(roles))
>>> roles
[(0, 'Three'), (1, 'Two'), (2, 'Investigator'), (3, 'One')]
>>> random.choice(roles)
(2, 'Investigator')
```